# Show Complete Pictures in Catalog

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have catalog of 6 picture. I am showing them in 1 row. On larger screens all 6 photos shows correctly, but when i change screen width to tablet size of mobile size, picture cuts in half.

The behaviour i want is that, show all 6 pictures on larger screen, but as soon as user window size, only picture which can be shown completely in that particular screen size show show, and other should get hide. Right now, I am using overflow: hidden and container of fixed size.

Below are some screenshots to show the issue,

[image: Screenshot of Catalog on Larger Screens]

[image: Screenshot of Catalog on Medium Size Screen]

[image: Screenshot of Catalog on Mobile Size Screen]

Comment: Give the Html coding to see how you implemented, use media screen query in your Sass or css

Comment: Though, this is not an uncommon issue and concern, and I'm sure it could be answered, @Fussionweb is correct, you should provide a code sample demonstrating what you've done and that reproduces this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too general but I think this would be a sample for it.

add below styles to the div wraps images.

```
.wrapper {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   overflow: hidden;

   // the following styles are optional but you must specify width and height
   width: 100%;
   height: 320px;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

and add these styles to images.

```
img {
   height: 100%;
   width: auto;

   // optional
   margin-right: 50px;
   margin-top: 50px;
}
```

The wrapper styles make that images wrap in multiple lines if they expand the wrapper width and `overflow: hidden` makes that only single line shows

Answer (score 0):

Use `width:100%` on `img` tag in html

OR

You can use it n your style-sheet like

```
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

also try to use `objectfit:contain` if you `img` has some fixed `height width`

Comment: probably just wants wrapping on the container, not modify the image size and scaling.

Comment: Then target that accordingly like `.container img{ width: 100%;}`

Comment: And also why are you using overflow hidden?

Answer (score 0):

here is amir mahdi digbari expanded solution in action.

You can achieve the same with css grid but flexbox is good enough for this.

```css
.img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.container {
  width: 1250px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img">Img1</div>
    <div class="img">Img2</div>
    <div class="img">Img3</div>
    <div class="img">Img4</div>
    <div class="img">Img5</div>
    <div class="img">Img6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Happy coding!